# C++ Byte Array Initializing - What's Wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I'm suddenly having a trouble with an array of bytes in an embedded C++ project (Arduino).

The bytes are #defined in a separate file which is generated elsewhere, and pulled into my project. Then they are used in calculations.  But after I load the bytes into the array, the first two keep changing on me. (!)

So in that other file I have:

```
#define MY_BYTES 0x26,0x28,0X1B,0X52,0X07,0X62,0X62
```

in one file, then in another file I use them with:

```
#define ARRAY_SZ 7
void doMyStuff() {
   uint8_t  MyStuff[ARRAY_SZ] = { MY_BYTES };

   Serial.print(" The 1st bytes: ");
   Serial.print(MyStuff[0], HEX);
   Serial.print(", "); 
   Serial.print(MyStuff[1], HEX);
   Serial.print(", "); 
   Serial.println(MyStuff[2], HEX);

   etc...
}
```

And when it runs I get

```
The 1st bytes: 36, 0, 1B
```

If I intervene and stick in some direct assignments after the declaration, I can over write them with:

```
MyStuff[0] = 0x26;
MyStuff[1] = 0x28;
```

..., and the first two are then correct, like the rest of them (there are actually 20 bytes, I've shrunk it for brevity here).  But I can't figure out why assignment in the declaration fails.

I moved everything into the same file, losing the #define, and initialized it with:

```
uint8_t MyStuff[] = {0x26,0x28,0x1B,0x52,0x07,0x62};
```

Still the problem. Am I missing something about arrays in C++?  I just can't get those first two bytes to be right, without direct assignments.  I don't seem to be low on RAM, and no other operations are happening between my assignment and readback, so I wouldn't think something else is treading on that memory.

Probably something obvious I'm missing here?

Edit: As pointed out this is in the Arduino enviroment which is a subset of C++ (changed my title). The proj I'm working on has a mix of C and C++ modules hence my mistake.

Comment: `Probably something obvious I'm missing here?` If it's obvious, then count me in as someone who can't find things in plain sight. :)

Comment: Is this over-simplified? My first guess is something is smashing the stack, but nothing here would obviously be doing that. What happens if you set the array to be "const uint8_t", so that it gets put somewhere else in memory?

Comment: Or a more basic question... what compiler warnings are you getting?

Comment: Change calls to `Serial.print` with `printf("%x", MyStuff[i]);` and see what happens. If problem is corrected then `Serial.print` is screwing you array.

Comment: 1) How does only changing order `Serial.print(MyStuff[1], HEX); Serial.print(", "); Serial.print(MyStuff[0], HEX);` affect output?  2) Suggest `Serial.print((int) MyStuff[1], HEX);`

Comment: Thx for suggestions. Tried the const declaration, which makes it work, though I need the array to be alterable to use a diff set of bytes from hard-coded ones depending on a condition.  Agree that the stack is prob getting munged - doing a thorough check of var size declares now.  Compiler warnings - turning on verbose display and will see what is there.

Comment: Chux: That doesn't have any impact.

Answer (score 1):

I  had the exact same issue in an Arduino program. It turned out to be some 3rd party code overwriting my array in the Data section. See here [Mosquitto socket read error Arduino client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339952/mosquitto-socket-read-error-arduino-client) for how I debugged what it was.

Comment: It's a good point - I suspect it could be Asynclabs Wifi stack munging that part of SRAM during a network operation. Will take a close look at your link.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no such constructions as

```
Serial.print(MyStuff[1], HEX);
```

in C. except as it was pointed out by **Jashaszun**  Serial is an instance of a structure and print is its data member (function pointer). But usually names of instances are written in lower case letters. So it looks like you are using C++.

If you will substitute this call for simple printf( "%d", MyStuff[1] ) you will get the correct value.
So the problem is in this construction that is in function pointed by `print`

```
Serial.print(MyStuff[1], HEX);
```

Here is a demonstrative code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MY_BYTES 0x26,0x28,0X1B,0X52,0X07,0X62,0X62 


int main(void) 
{
    uint8_t a[] = {MY_BYTES};
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
38 40 27 82 7 98 98
```

Comment: Well, technically `Serial` could be an instance of a structure and `print` could be defined like this: `void (*print)(uint8_t, int)`. So there *is* such a construction as `Serial.print(MyStuff[1], HEX);` in C.

Comment: Admittedly, that's not very likely, but just saying.

Comment: Given that Serial.print is apparently overloaded, it's either C++ or that this the problem.

Comment: @Chris Arguin it is not overloaded. it seems has the second parameter of an enumeration type which controls the function behaviour.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow he uses the same function to print strings. Either it is overloaded or some abuse of varargs is happening, in which case I'd look there first.

Comment: `Serial.print` is arduino-specific, and IIRC it uses some superset of C (wire or something).

Comment: @Drew McGowen I thinl I should delete my post.:)

Comment: Sorry yes, it's Arduino where I forget the std libraries are all C++, though only a subset of C++ is supported. Drew's comment is good - it's more like a superset of C.